# Whose integral is $\ln(x)$ in $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

It is well know that $\ln(x)$ is the primitive of $\frac 1 x$. Can we find a function $f$ such that $\int_0^x f(t) dt = \ln(x)$ when $x\in(0,1)$?

I forgot to say that I was looking for a function in $L_{loc}^1(0,1)$, especially integrable in $(0, T) \ \forall T \le 1$. The $\frac 1 t$ does not work because it is not integrable in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Isn't that the other way around? That being said, the answer to what OP wrote seems to be just $1/t$.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood something since your two sentences are basically saying the same thing. $F$ is a primitive/antiderivative/indefinite integral of $f$ if $F(t)=\int f(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$. It's the same thing but phrased algebraically instead of in natural language.

Comment: I forgot to add the lower bound of integration. See the edited question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation $\int^x f(t)dt$ doesn't quite make sense, because it lacks a lower limit of integration. That said,

$$\ln x=\int_1^x{dt\over t}$$

is true for *all* positive values of $x$, including those in $(0,1)$, where the integration picks up a minus sign because it runs "backwards" from $1$ to $x$. I.e., for $0\lt x\lt 1$, we have

$$\int_1^x{dt\over t}=-\int_x^1{dt\over t}=\text{ the negative of an area beneath a curve between two points}$$

This agrees with what we know about the logarithm, namely that it is positive for $x\gt1$ and negative for $x\lt 1$.

Comment: +1) As a side note to your useful answer, It is interesting if you perform a u-sub $1/t=u$ then the rule $ln(1/t)=-lnt$ follows, confirming your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

For the edited question: No. If we had $\ln(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$ it would follow that $f(x)=1/x$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, but $\int_0^xdt/t$ does not exist.

**Details** added in response to a comment:

Fine, FTC applies to $\int_a^b f$ where $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $1/t$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$. This is no problem:

Suppose $\int_0^x f=\ln x$ for all $x>0$. For $x>1$ we have $$\ln x=\int_0^1f(t)\,dt+\int_1^xf(t)\,dt=c+\int_1^xf(t)\,dt.$$Differentiating both sides shows that $$\frac1x=f(x)\quad(x>1).$$A similar argument shows that in fact $f(x)=1/x$ for all $x>0$. So $\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ does not exist.

Comment: To apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, you need a closed interval $[a, b]$ that $f$ is well defined in $[a, b]$..

Comment: @OlivierdeJussieu See edit...